# Datagrid entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, datagrid, xamarin.forms.entry

Does anyone know is it possible to achieve an entry like the picture I have attached below? I would like to have a data grid to display data from database. I have tried using Xamarin.Forms.Datagrid but it does not allow rows to be added manually. My objective is to display the parameters in such a manner for easier viewing (similar to excel sheet format) but Xamarin has really limited controls...Just wondering if anyone know any other ways to achieve it?

[image]

This is my code for datagrid. I was only able to create Column with names but not the rows.

```
<dg:DataGrid HeaderHeight="50"
         BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 1"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 2"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 3"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 4"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 5"/>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 6"/>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: But if you are loading the data from a database, why are you against binding those values to the `Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create the this kind of Entry.

Do you want to achieve the result like this sceenshot?
[image]

If so, you should add this layout in your xaml folder.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectionEnabled="True"
               RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8">

            <dg:DataGrid.HeaderFontSize>
                <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>15</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    <OnIdiom.Phone>13</OnIdiom.Phone>
                </OnIdiom>
            </dg:DataGrid.HeaderFontSize>

            <dg:DataGrid.Columns>


                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Team" PropertyName="Name" Width="2*"/>
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Win" PropertyName="Win" Width="0.95*"/>
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Loose" PropertyName="Loose"  Width="1*"/>
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Home" PropertyName="Home"/>
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Percentage" PropertyName="Percentage" StringFormat="{}{0:0.00}" />

            </dg:DataGrid.Columns>


        </dg:DataGrid>
    </StackLayout>
```

If you do not know how to add rows in this control. For example,

`<dg:DataGridColumn Title="Team" PropertyName="Name" Width="2*"/>`

above line have three attribute, `Title`, `PropertyName` , `Width`.

`Title`: mean first line Team, win, loose, home, percentage titles.

`Width`: mean width of this `Column`

If you want to add data blew the `Title` ,you should use `PropertyName` attribute.

In the layout background, you add binding context.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Here is my `MyViewModel.cs`

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();

            Teams.Add(new Team() {  Home = "lost1", Win = "31", Loose="1", Name="cava", Percentage="91" }) ;
            Teams.Add(new Team() {  Home = "lost2", Win = "31", Loose = "2", Name = "cava", Percentage = "91" });
            Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "lost3", Win = "31", Loose = "3", Name = "cava", Percentage = "91" });
            Teams.Add(new Team() {  Home = "lost4", Win = "31", Loose = "4", Name = "cava", Percentage = "91 "});
            Teams.Add(new Team() {  Home = "lost5", Win = "31", Loose = "5", Name = "cava", Percentage = "91" });
            Teams.Add(new Team() {  Home = "lost6", Win = "31", Loose = "6", Name = "cava", Percentage = "91",  });
        }
    }
```

Here is my `Team` code.

```
  public class Team
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Win { get; set; }
        public string Loose { get; set; }
        public string Home { get; set; }
        public string Percentage { get; set; }



    }
```

[image]

Here is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/DataGridDemo1.zip

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help! I understood a lot better about datagrid from your post! :) It works well

Comment: But sorry hi. Is it possible to create entry inside the rows? Like for user to key in a value in row under any columns?

Comment: Yes, you can add entry to it, please refer to this thread. https://imgur.com/a/pW5hcYZ

Comment: Okay thanks! If I want to only allow entry for a particular row is it possible? Can I ask if the only way adding rows is just using property name with binding? I would like to add another empty row for entries. What I did was adding new row in viewmodel without any properties but not sure how to access it to use entries in it